# Please check my predicate logic answer

Tags: predicate-logic

I have a been working on a predicate logic question and wondered if someone could check my answer and possibly point me in the correct direction should it be wrong.

question: Let A be the set of DM students, B the set of BA students and S all students. Formalise the following.

P: If someone is a student of DM, then they must study BA.

my answer: ∃x A(x)-> B(x)

Q: If there exists atleast one student of DM, then all students of BA study DM

my answer;  ∃x  ∈ A(x)-> (B(x) and A(x))

R: If all students of BA study DM then none studies DM

my answer; ∀x (B(x) and A(x)) -> ∀x A(x)

Comment: I think you need to review quantifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would write:

P: $(\forall\,x)(A(x)\to B(x)) $

Q: $(\exists\,x\in A(x))\to [(\forall\,x)(B(x)\to A(x))]$

R: $[(\forall\,x)(B(x)\to A(x))]\to[\neg(\exists x)(A(x))] $

Comment: Thanks, i definately tripped up on the quantifiers. Do the brackets make much difference?

Comment: Not really. Some authors always use them, some don't. If clarity suffers from the lack, then USE THEM.